# Updating records using a Repository Pattern with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, repository-pattern

I'm writing a simple blog application and trying to establish CRUD operations in my generic repository pattern but I'm getting an error on my update method that says:

> 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for
>   'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I followed a [post that explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035323/mocking-or-faking-dbentityentry-or-creating-a-new-dbentityentry) how to 'fake' Entry() by adding additional level of indirection over DbContext. However in MVC 5 we're inheriting from: **IdentityDbContext** and not DbContext. I did try implementing the authors fix but the error persists.

### My Question

How can I add an update method to my repository in Entity Framework 6 using IdentityDbContext? If we aren't supposed to do it this way then how do I update a record with this pattern?

I should note that all other the other methods work as expected.

**My generic Repository:**

```
public class BlogEngineRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

        public BlogEngineRepository(DbContext dataContext)
        {
            DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
        }

        #region IRepository<T> Members

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        { 

           DbSet.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        }

        public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(predicate);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet;
        }

        public T GetById(int id)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update should look like ([expanding on Dan Beaulieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30067009/209259)) :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,IntroText,Body,Modified,Author")] Post post)
{
    using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        post.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        uwork.PostRepository.Update(post);

        uwork.Commit();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**RepositoryPattern looks like this:**

```
public class BlogEngineRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
  public BlogEngineRepository(DbContext dataContext)
  {
    DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    Context = dataContext;
  }

  public T Update(T entity)
  {
     DbSet.Attach(entity);
     var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
     entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
  }
}
```

You can view a full explaination to the answer for [Efficient way of updating list of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421370/efficient-way-of-updating-list-of-entities/11421706#11421706) for more information on the details of just an update.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Erik. I haven't really evaluated this pattern for a while but this seems like such an obvious win for those looking to implement an explicit `Update` method. +1

Comment: A change for EF Core, EntityState.Modified can now be found in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore instead of System.Data

Answer (score 25):

Ok, I figured this out. The reason why there isn't an *Update* method in new repository patterns (Entity Framework 6) is because **there's no need for one**. You simply fetch your record by id, make your changes and then commit/save.

**For example, this is my edit POST method from my postController:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,IntroText,Body,Modified,Author")] Post post)
{
    using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        Post edit = uwork.PostRepository.GetById(post.Id);
        edit.Title = post.Title;
        edit.IntroText = post.IntroText;
        edit.Body = post.Body;
        edit.Modified = DateTime.Now;

        uwork.Commit();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**RepositoryPattern looks like this:**

```
public class BlogEngineRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public BlogEngineRepository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    } 

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity); 
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your repository do still have an Update method. Given your explanation, I'd guess it's not needed, isn't it?

Comment: @Alisson you're correct, that was a careless copy and paste.

Comment: Good example, bad in practice.  [With EF there is no need to hit the database (select) to update object back (update)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421370/efficient-way-of-updating-list-of-entities/11421706#11421706).

Comment: I'm confused here because in Edit Post method we already received the object of type 'Post' with the updated values. So why do we need to call                 
Post edit = uwork.PostRepository.GetById(post.Id);                                           
to return a new object and then fetch the post properties and assign the values ? Can't we just use what we received as the parameter ?   Also how it possible to update  just calling   uwork.Commit();  here ? and if this is OK then why we need to have fetch the values rather than calling Commit(); only ? This may sound crazy but I'm confused