# Table columns are getting updated as NULL if i dont defined them in my Controller action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Problem is Table Columns are getting updated with NULL if i dont defined them in my controller.Below is my Controller Action.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult GetEditRecord(UserDetail MU, string actiontype)
    {
        if (actiontype == "Save")
        {
            UserDetail Ud = new UserDetail();
            _unitOfWork = new GenericUnitOfWork();
            Ud.ID = MU.ID;
            Ud.FirstName = MU.FirstName;
            Ud.LastName = MU.LastName;
            Ud.IsDeleted = false;
            Ud.FkCompanyId = 5;
            Ud.FkRegionId = 1;
            _unitOfWork.GetRepoInstance<UserDetail>().update(Ud);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers"); ;
    }
```

I Have 10 columns in UserDetails but i need to edit only 6 columns but when i click on update the other fields are getting save as NULL. Below is My GeneralRepository code to update Entity

```
 public void update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;        

    }
```

Please tell if i am missing something.

Comment: You're creating a new item then saving them `Ud = new UserDetail();`, tihs will overwrite all existing data. If you don't want this you need to read the data out the db, update it, then save it back.

Comment: I have edit option in my page and after clicking on that i have to show 6 columns only but in table i have 10 columns.Please let me know which code i need to share as i am not getting the thing you saying about read the data.

Comment: What ORM are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating records using a Repository Pattern with Entity Framework 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066247/updating-records-using-a-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-6)

Comment: code first approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is reasonable, you are basically creating new record and your default values are NULL.

You should probably want to first locate your record (FindById or something) and then update it.

Unrelated: Shouldn't unit of work be disposable?

Comment: yes it is implementing the IDisposable class already. and i am retrieving the data by Edit option then Update button come.

Comment: @Steve if you don't call `Dispose()`, it doesn't matter that the class implements IDisposable. The object will stay around, probably holding open transactions and connections, until the GC collects it